# ActionScript 3.0 TypeError #1009

Tags: actionscript, typeerror

I am making a game in Flash CS6 with ActionScript 3.0, and my game can run properly but an error keeps popping up and I can't seem to solve it. The solutions I've found online aren't specific enough to my program.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at farmgame227_fla::MainTimeline/onenter()[farmgame227_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:133]
```

The line of frame two that is in question will vary depending on how I make the game end. Here are examples of the code in question.

```
import flash.events.Event;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);

var myscore = 0;

function onenter(e:Event)
{

if (sheep1.y < 0 || sheep1.y > 775 || sheep1.x < 0 || sheep1.x > 775)
    {       
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);
    nextFrame();
}

if (hand.hitTestObject (goat))
{       
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);
    nextFrame();
}

score.text = myscore;
```

That isn't all of the code, but I just included the lines that seem to be in question with the debugger.

I have tried searching for multiple solutions to my problem, including debugging, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the line at 133?

Comment: line 133 is `if (sheep1.y < 0 || sheep1.y > 775...` etc. I gave the other line of code that includes `hand.hitTestObject (goat)` as another example of a line that the debugger will point to if that action were to occur instead of the one on line 133. I think the problem has something to do with either the removal of the Event Listener or moving to the next frame, but I'm not sure how to go about solving it

Comment: are you sure sheep1  is not null? add a check before the problematic line like if(sheep==null) trace("some message"); because the error exactly this says, at the line 133 you try to call a method or a property of a null object

Comment: Sadly, I won't be able to access a computer with Flash on it for a week, so I can't test it right now, but I will once I get back to my school that has it.If it were null, what would be my next step? and what would be another idea for a solution if it ends up not being null? Thanks